# JMeter While Controller - how to increment the variable

Tags: variables, jmeter, increment

This is what I'd like to do in JMeter, retrieve the data in xml from the server,  and continue retrieving until reaching at a certain number.

```
While ( totalNumOfNodes < 1000 ) {
   1. HpptRequest
   2. nodeCntInResp = extract from HttpResponse
   3. totalNumOfNodes += nodeCntInResp
}
```

I can do step 1 and 2, but how can I do the step 3?  What element should I use for this?

Comment: You should use a [Loop controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

Comment: It looks like your iteration count is not fixed, if so, you should maintain a variable for `totalNumOfNodes` update it after parsing `HttpResponse` and use a [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) which should be configured with the stop condition `totalNumOfNodes < 1000`

Comment: What I really wanted to know was .. "update it after parsing HttpResponse" from your kind answer .. :)   Is this something I can do using Bean Shell Sampler ??

Comment: It's late here so I can't give a detailed answer, hopefully you'll get the needed answer, else i'll pick it up in the morning. I think shell sampler isn't necessary, this can be accomplished using a custom User defined variable, totalNumOfNodes which you would increment after extracting the count from HttpResponse. The condition will be like `${totalNumOfNodes} <1000`

Comment: I have added an answer, hope it helps. Bean Shell did turn out to be a good choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this, using a BeanShell PostProcessor is a good choice. For my testing, I used random.org to get a random number that I use to simulate `nodeCntInResp` e.g. the link below will give a random number between 1 and 300

https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=300&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new

My BeanShell PostProcessor script looks like this:

```
    response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
    vars.put("incrementBy", response);
    try {
         int incrementNum = 0; 
         try {
          incrementNum = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("incrementBy").trim());
         } catch(Exception ex) {
            //Ignore
         }
         int totalIterNum = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("TotalIter").trim());
        int newIterCount = incrementNum + totalIterNum;
        vars.put("TotalIter", String.valueOf(newIterCount));
        log.warn("Value from HTTP Response: " + incrementNum);
        log.warn("Total Iterations Value: " + newIterCount);
        if(newIterCount > 1000) {
            vars.put("TERMINATE_COND", "FALSE");
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("Error in my script", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
```

The While controller is configured with condition: `${TERMINATE_COND}` which I set to `FALSE` in the script above once the total iteration count exceeds 1000.

My jmeter setup is like below:
[image]

You can find a sample jmeter test file for the above test done with Jmeter 2.11 at [this link](https://github.com/vsnyc/soutils/blob/master/codepuzzles/src/main/resources/jmeter/sample_http_test.jmx)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!  It works fine ...  I'm a newbie for jmeter ...  it is more verbose than I expected ...  :)

Comment: Some of the verbosity in my script is just for debugging purposes and error handling, you can eliminate most of it if you trust your data. random.org was throwing SocketExceptions so I had to wrap it in try/catch

Answer (score 2):

How about Beanshell script:

```
long number = Long.parseLong(vars.get("totalNumOfNodes ")); 
totalNumOfNodes = totalNumOfNodes + nodeCntInResp ;
vars.put("number", String.valueOf(totalNumOfNodes ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for point 3 [__intSum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) function is what you're looking for.

As per [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) guide:

> The `__intSum` function is trivial but it can be very useful for instances when the sum of two or more integers (increment or decrement) is required.
>
> Examples:
>
> `${__intSum(1,5,)}` - will return 6
> `${__intSum(1,5,8)}` - will return 14
> `${__intSum(1,5,8,SUM)}` - will return 14 and store it to SUM variable
> `${__intSum(10,-5)}` - will return 5
> `${__intSum(${A},${B})}` - will return an evaluation of A and B variables integer representation sum, which can be handy for Counter value processing.